# BigQuery: How to get a list of all views across an organisation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We want to understand what views we have in all our BigQuery instances across our organisation and were wondering what the best method to do this is.

Our current attempt uses the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` view and attempts to list all views across a region (`region-eu`):

```sql
select *
from region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

However, this lists views by project, not in the entire region let alone the organisation.

**What's the best way to see a list of all views with respective projects and dataset?**

*(Either via SQL or `bq`)*

#### Update

Managed to get views listed for a given project using:

```bash
bq ls --format json \
  | jq '.[].id' \
  | tr : . \
  | xargs -L1 -I'{}' bq query --format json --nouse_legacy_sql 'select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name from `{}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`' \
  | jq '.[]'
```

With output looking like:

```
{
  "table_catalog": "project1",
  "table_name": "dataset1",
  "table_schema": "one_view"
}
{
  "table_catalog": "project1",
  "table_name": "dataset2",
  "table_schema": "two_view"
}
```

Unfortunately, no luck with organisation yet.

Comment: as guillaume said, view list can't be scanned unless you have named views in particular pattern. example using gcloud asset api at org level, you can grep the pattern : gcloud asset list --organization=your_org_id--asset-types='bigquery.googleapis.com/Table' | egrep 'View'

Comment: That's more what I was looking for, however it looks like you have to filter by table name and our views unfortunately don't have a naming pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out using a mixture of `gcloud`, `bq`, and `jq`.

```bash
gcloud projects list --format json \
| jq -r '.[].projectId' \
| xargs -L1 -I'{}' bq ls --format json --project_id {} \
| grep '\[' \
| jq -r '.[].id' \
| tr : . \
| xargs -L1 -I'{}' bq query --format json --nouse_legacy_sql 'select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name from `{}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`' \
| jq '.[]' \
| jq -s . > all_views_in_org.json
```

What this does:

1. List all project IDs (lines 1 and 2)
2. List all the dataset IDs in each project and filter out projects that don't have bigquery enabled (by lazily filtering for JSON responses) (lines 3-5)
3. Replace `:` with `.` so the IDs can be used in SQL (line 6)
4. Query each dataset to list all the views in the dataset (line 7)
5. Extract the JSON and combine all results from all datasets into an array saving this to a file `all_views_in_org.json` (lines 8 and 9)

Results will be a JSON file looking like:

```json
[
  {
    "table_catalog": "project1",
    "table_name": "dataset1",
    "table_schema": "view1"
  },
  {
    "table_catalog": "project1",
    "table_name": "dataset1",
    "table_schema": "view2"
  },
  {
    "table_catalog": "project1",
    "table_name": "dataset2",
    "table_schema": "view1"
  },
  {
    "table_catalog": "project2",
    "table_name": "dataset1",
    "table_schema": "view1"
  },
  ...
]
```

This should work for any organisation.

Answer (score 1):

View are only per region per project or per dataset. You have the scope documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views#scope_and_syntax).

Some resources can by scanned at org level, you have the list [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro). But not the views.

Comment: Yeah I did notice this, however was wondering if it's possible another way

Comment: Out of the box no. You can create a loop over all the project in your org, but it will be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting answer from [philMarius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045547/18904955) for Windows and Powershell:

```
gcloud projects list --format json |
jq -r '.[].projectId' |
%{bq ls --format json --project_id $_} |
Select-String '\[' |
jq -r '.[].id' |
%{$_.Replace(':', '.')} |
%{bq query --format json --nouse_legacy_sql "select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name from ``$_.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS``"} |
jq '.[]' |
jq -s . |
Out-File -FilePath ./all_views_in_org.json
```

Note: You will need [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) available in your **PATH**